# Change value of element in xml file which is based on raml21.xsd schema in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, raml

below is xml file which I want to update (for example - change dateTime attribute in log element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<raml xmlns="raml21.xsd" version="2.1">
  <cmData id="3221225472" scope="all" type="plan">
    <header>
      <log action="created" appInfo="Nokia BTS Site Manager" appVersion="FL16" dateTime="2016-09-23T17:59:59" user="BTSSM"/>
    </header>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

Here is my code:

```
filePath = openFileDialogXml.FileName;
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(filePath);
XmlElement node1 = document.SelectSingleNode("/header/log") as XmlElement;
if (node1 != null)
{
  node1.Attributes[3].Value = "test";
}
document.Save(filePath);
```

But, the problem is: node1 is always null. I now the problem cause this line in xml file:

```
raml xmlns="raml21.xsd" version="2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to factor the namespace in when finding elements. And include all the elements between the target and root in the XPath

Use the overload of `SelectSingleNode` that takes a `XmlNamespaceManager`, having configured the latter to include the required namespace.

Something like:

```cs
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("x", "raml21.xsd");
var node1 = document.SelectSingleNode("/x:raml/x:cmData /x:header/x:log", mgr) as XmlElement;
```